# Search a location in google maps using r selenium

Tags: r, google-maps, search, selenium-webdriver

I am using  the Selenium package in R to search a certain location on google maps and then isolate the post code and coordinates of the place as they appear in the URL using the getURL() function once the search is completed.

Here is my code:

```
library("RSelenium")
startServer()
checkForServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
#Openning the URLs
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/maps/place/ KURUVIKKANANM +Kerela")
```

I am able to input the URL but cannot find a way to press the search button on google maps to actually find the place.

Does any one know how to find and click on the DOM element for search on google maps? Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these two lines:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'class', "searchbox-searchbutton")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("R Cran", key = "enter"))
```

The first one is the search button, and the second one sends the enter key.

You can also change the second line to:

```
webElem$clickElement()
```

in order to simulate a mouse click.

Comment: Thank you for post @R. Schifini. I tried to execute your suggestion; however I get the following error: 
Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
         Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
         class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
Do you know what might be going wrong. Thank you so much for the previous post -- I really appreciate it.

Comment: The first line searches for an element using class.  What you should do is determine the name of the class of the search button.  Right click on the search button and do Inspect Element. Take note on the name of its class and then change the first line accordingly.

Comment: I just updated the element to : webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'class', "searchbox-searchbutton-container")
And it works very well. Thank you so much @R. Schifini